# How to make a new column after four items are echoed?

Tags: php, html

So, I'm making a shop for my virtual, online game and I want there to be four items for every row. The items are fetched from the database. I'm using bulma for the css framework. I basically want the rows to be a little like this: http://bloxtopia.xyz/Shop/ <- (Where the items are)

Here's what it would look like on the front end side

```html
        <div class="column">
          item 1
          </div><div class="column">
          item 2
          </div><div class="column">
          item 3
          </div><div class="column">
item 4
          </div></div> <div class='columns'><div class="column">
item 5 on new line because of (<div class='columns'><div class="column">)
          </div>
```

So basically, after every four items are echoed, `<div class='columns'>`is added

Comment: a counter and the Modulo(%) operator is all you need. can't be specific without seeing the code

Comment: Doesn't seem to need MySQL to do anything; this is a front end presentational issue. Suggest you remove the tags

Comment: use class `is-one-quarter`, the fifth will be on the next row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a specific need to create a new group of columns?  Bulma allows multiline column containers. https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/options/

As @Christhofer Natalius mentioned, use `.is-one-quarter` on the columns, but don't forget the `.is-multiline` on the main `.columns` container!

This method allows you to not care how many items are returned, they will wrap accordingly without needing to make a new column wrapper for every 4 items.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.4/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="columns is-multiline is-mobile">
  <div class="column is-one-quarter">item 1</div>
   <div class="column is-one-quarter">item 2</div>
   <div class="column is-one-quarter">item 3</div>
   <div class="column is-one-quarter">item 4</div>
   <div class="column is-one-quarter">item 5</div>
   <div class="column is-one-quarter">item 6</div>
   <div class="column is-one-quarter">item 7</div>
   <div class="column is-one-quarter">item 8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, it will automatically return you 4-columns in a row.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<h2>Four Equal Columns</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why reinvent the wheel when OP already using CSS framework to do this?